# Converting data in columns to rows - Qlikview Load

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table like the below in an excel sheet:

| Person | Food | Drink | Snack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sandwich | Water | Crisps |
| B | Wrap | Coke | Crisps |
| C | Pasta | Coke | Crisps |
| D | Sandwich | Juice | Banana |
| E | Burger | Coke | Crisps |

I want to transform it to the below table while loading the data to qlikview

| Person | Item |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sandwich |
| A | Water |
| A | Crisps |
| B | Wrap |
| B | Coke |
| B | Crisps |
| C | Pasta |
| C | Coke |
| C | Crisps |
| D | Sandwich |
| D | Juice |
| D | Banana |
| E | Burger |
| E | Coke |
| E | Crisps |

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different way would be with a crosstable.

```
Data:
load * inline [
Person, Food,   Drink,  Snack
A,  Sandwich,   Water,  Crisps
B,  Wrap,   Coke,   Crisps
C,  Pasta,  Coke,   Crisps
D,  Sandwich,   Juice,  Banana
E,  Burger, Coke,   Crisps];

NEW_Table:
crosstable(Name,Item,1)
load * resident Data;

drop table Data;
drop field Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the laziest way is to loop though all the fields and concatenate them.

The annotated script below will produce the following result:
[image: Data view]

```
RawData:
LOAD 
    Person, 
    Food, 
    Drink, 
    Snack
FROM
    [C:\Users\User\Documents\data.xlsx]
    (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1)
;

// loop through all the fields in RawData table
for i = 1 to NoOfFields('RawData')
    // get the name of the field in the current iteration
    let fieldName = FieldName($(i), 'RawData');
    
    // field "Person" should not be included    
    if('$(fieldName)' <> 'Person') then
        // resident load from RawData table the Person field
        // and the field name from the current iteration
        // name the new field "Item"
        // because the table in each iteration is having the same 
        // name and the same fields Qlik will concatenate the result
        // to an existing table
        Result:
        Load
            Person,
            [$(fieldName)] as Item 
        Resident
            RawData
        ;
    
    end if

next

// if RawData table is not needed anymore
Drop Table RawData;
```